# How does Spanish handle plurals of numbers?

Tags: plurales, números

In English, we have: **To simulate this situation, we assign 29 1s and 21 0s .**
*This means that we labeling 29 members 1s and 21 members 0s in an experiment.*

How does Spanish handle plural numbers in its sentences 1s and 0s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/plurals-of-numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would say `ceros` and `unos`. Numbers form plurals as any other word: adding `-s` or `-es`.

The exceptions are the plurals of `dos` and `tres`. In zones where the pronunciation of `c/z` and `s` is different, they say `doses` and `treses`, but in the rest of the Spanish speaking world the plural of those numbers is just `dos` and `tres` (so as not to confuse them with `doces` and `treces`).

`Seis` is sometimes pluralized as `seises`, sometimes left as is.

Numbers in plural are written in words. If it's too cumbersome, you can prepend “números” and write them in figures, as in “123 números 0”.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Angus is correct, I would only like to add that in written Spanish is not correct or usual to use numbers (as digits) but words. The correct translation for the sentence you wrote would be:

```
This means that we labeling 29 members 1s and 21 members 0s in an experiment.
```

En Español:

```
Eso indica que etiquetamos veintinueve miembros con unos y ventiún miembros con ceros en un experimento.
```